# How do I update within insert query in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to perform sql operations with c++
my problem is I have created a travel table using below stmt

```
stmt->execute("CREATE TABLE  travel(src VARCHAR(20), dest VARCHAR(20), ppkm INT(10), km INT(50), total INT(50))");
```

I am inserting values into travel table using below stmt

```
stmt->execute("INSERT INTO travel VALUES('MYS', 'BAN', 6, 150, 'UPDATE travel SET total = ppkm * km')");
```

I get successful execution and values are inserted, but only for final insert value that is total I get 0 instead must be 6 * 150 = 900. Kindly help me out with update query syntax.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what dhould that query exactly do? Update all records when inserting?

Comment: ya please help me out with syntax of multiplying two values of same table how do i do it and insert it ????

Comment: it's not possible insert data in run time for this you create procedure or trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the total to the product of the two values, then you can use a trigger to set it automatically.  More reasonably, just do it in the insert:

```
INSERT INTO travel(src, dest, ppkm, km, total)
    SELECT 'MYS', 'BAN', 6, 150, 6 * 150
```

You can also do what you want using a view.  Create the table without the total column and then create a view with the total:

```
create view v_travel as
    select t.*, ppkm * km as total
    from travel t;
```

Or you can do this manually after the insert:

```
INSERT INTO travel(src, dest, ppkm, km)
    SELECT 'MYS', 'BAN', 6, 150;

UPDATE travel
    SET total = ppkem * km;
```

Comment: You cannot reference the column values you are inserting in the `SELECT` of the `INSERT` in your first statement.

Comment: Thank you found it helpful.

Comment: I need another help from you. I need to display output of mysql with my c++ program. I have completed inserting and updating values just cannot figure out how do i display its output

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO travel VALUES('MYS', 'BAN', 6, 150, 'UPDATE travel SET total = ppkm * km')
```

Is valid, but you are trying to `INSERT` the text `'UPDATE travel SET total = ppkm * km'` into an INT field, which is converted to 0 as the first character, 'U', is not a digit.

You must do the calculation manually if you want it as part of the INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO travel VALUES('MYS', 'BAN', 6, 150, 6*150);
```

Or use a `TRIGGER`, or do not store the calculated value and use a view instead as suggested by Gordon.

As an aside, `INT(50)` is meaningless as an `INT` will never have more than 10 digits. If you need more then use a `BIGINT`.

Comment: your insert statement is totally wrong in update query you use single quot in this condition mysql predict as Character values

Comment: @AshutoshSIngh, The top statement is copied from the OP.. and is directly followed by a description of why it doesn't work.